# gcc using X11 lib

Tags: gcc, x11

I'm trying to compile C code under suse 11 with -lX11 option (gcc 3.4.3) : `gcc -L/home/user/myDir -lX11 myprog.c -o myprog`

The error is : `/usr/lib/ld : cannot find -lX11`

I tried many paths where X11 is mentioned : `/usr/lib/` , `/usr/lib/X11`, ..., but the error persists. The problem happens on my new machine, indeed I have changed it and have installed exactly the same OS and packages as the previous one where the compilation worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution : 
change : `/usr/lib/libX11.so.6` to `/usr/lib/libX11.so`

Comment: Renaming system libraries is a bad idea. What should have happened is that `ldconfig` created symlinks from libX11.so.6 to libX11.so (you can still create the symlink yourself, of course)

Comment: I agree, finally what I did is copying the library from my old machine to the new one